# Laravel PHP - Array not passed to View

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have a question about simple laravel code which is not working.

This is how the route looks:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{ 
    $chill = array(
            'heading' => 'Hello Laravel', 
            'body'    => 'This is totally awesome'
    );
    return View::make('test', $chill);
});
```

This is how the view looks in `test.php`:

```
{{ $heading }}

{{ $body }}
```

I don't understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to name your view

```
test.blade.php
```

if you want to use blade in your view.

Then try this code here:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{ 
$chill = array(
'heading' => 'Hello Laravel', 
'body' => 'This is totally awesome'
 );
 return View::make('test')->with('chill', $chill);
 });
```

Then use this in your view:

```
 {{ $chill['heading'] }}

 {{ $chill['body'] }}
```

I hope that I don't have any minor errors but this should work now :)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help, but not working.. Here is what is get out: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sr3ksjwlj0x8nx/laravel.png

Comment: @user3270211 You are visiting the wrong url just visit `localhost/laravel` or `localhost/laravel/public` and check the results.

Comment: Bhai jaan! bohot chukrya! thank you, its working. Salam from Norway.